# How to save more that one byte array using Java AudioSystem.write

Tags: java, arrays, audio

```
    public void run(){
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream= new AudioInputStream(pis,audioFormat,samlpesCount);
            try {

                 AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                try {
                    pis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

`pis` is a `PipedInputStream`, through I send byte arrays with data.
This way I can save only 1 byte array of data. It don't waits for next piece of data.
Would you advice me something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WaveFileWriter like so:

```
InputStream in = ...;
OutputStream out = ...;

AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);

WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter();
writer.write(in, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, outStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution: `samlpesCount` have to be total samples count not only size of one arrray